# multiple condition using range in if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
$('#name').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which < 97 || e.which > 122){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Above code allow only alphabets only but in the same time it also disallow space to work. I know the code for space is 32, but how should I add that this scenario?

Comment: `if(e.which!=32 && (e.which < 97 || e.which > 122) && e.which )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `and` clause to exclude the value `32`

```js
$('#name').keypress(function(e) {
  snippet.log(e.which)
  if ((e.which < 97 || e.which > 122) && e.which != 32 && e.which != 45) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" />
```

Comment: dash's keycode is 189, I do e.whch != 189 it doesn't allow dash, any idea?

Comment: @Jennifer I think a `i` is missing in `whch`... also `-` is `45` I think

Comment: isn't this would be better for dash `String.fromCharCode(e.which) === "-"`?